# How to send email to multiple recipients separately in one button click

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, smtp, oledbconnection

I have a mailer in which I want to send mail to multiple recipients. The recipients can be from a database or an excel worksheet. Here is the code:

```
  protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GetAllRecipient();


        Msg = null;
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Email sent.');", true);

    }
  public void SendHTMLMail()
    {


       StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/one.html"));
        string readFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Regex regx = new Regex("(?<!src=\")http(s)?://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*([a-zA-Z0-9\\?\\#\\=\\/]){1})?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string output = regx.ToString();
        output = readFile;

        Msg.Body = output.ToString();
        Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        int i = 0;
        string username = Server.UrlEncode(this.txtUsername.Text);
        output = regx.Replace(output, new MatchEvaluator((match) =>
        {

            var url = Uri.EscapeDataString(match.Value.ToString());
            url = url.Replace("%3F", "&").Replace("%3D", "=");
            return $"http://localhost4654/two?sender={username}&link={url}&mailer_id={i}";
        }));

        Msg.From = new MailAddress(txtUsername.Text);
        Msg.Subject = null;

        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(txtUsername.Text, txtpwd.Text);
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    }
    public void GetAllRecipient()
    {
        if (RadioButton1.Checked)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT address FROM address1";
            cmd.Connection = sql;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sql.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            sql.Close();

                for (int a = 0; a < dt.Rows.Count; a++)
                {
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Msg.To.Add(row["address"].ToString());
                   SendHTMLMail();

                }
            }
        }

        else if (RadioButton2.Checked)
        {
            string connectionString = "";
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + fileName);
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileLocation);

                if (fileExtension == ".xls")
                {

                    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }
                else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                {
                    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }
                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                con.Open();
                DataTable dtExcelSheetName = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                string getExcelSheetName = dtExcelSheetName.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT address FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + "]";
                dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                dAdapter.Fill(dt);
                con.Close();

                for (int a = 0; a < dt.Rows.Count; a++)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        Msg.To.Add(row["address"].ToString());                       
                        SendHTMLMail();
                        smtp.Send(Msg);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (RadioButton3.Checked)
        {
            if (FileUpload2.HasFile)
            {

                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName);

                string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + fileName);
                FileUpload2.SaveAs(fileLocation);
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileLocation);

                String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                string[] toAddressArray;
                toAddressArray = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
                foreach (string a in toAddressArray)
                {
                    Msg.To.Add(a);

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

The problem I am facing is- When I send the mail, it is getting delivered to all the recipients in the same mail instead of delivering them separately. How can I send the mail separately, so that no two recipients get to know eachother.
Also, in my HTML page that I am sending as mail body, there are some links. When the recipient clicks any link , I am retrieving his mail id in the textbox "rep.text". So, I am getting the last name from the recipients list even if the person who clicked the link is say 4th or 5th. This same happens in case when I use BCC.

Comment: use Msg.Bcc.Add don't use Msg.To.Add

Comment: but here i am doing one more thing. In my html page that i am sending as mail body, there are some links. When the recipient clicks any link , i am retrieving his mail id. So, while using BCC as well, i am getting the last name from the bcc list even if the person who clicked the link is say 4th or 5th

Comment: i have edited the code @AdinugrahaTawaqal

Comment: Loop through all of the users and send each an email so they get their unique link.

Comment: since i an new to this platform so i don't know much about .net. Can you provide the code? @Scrobi

Comment: Can you show me part of code that generate this unique link?

Comment: just tell me how to loop through each recipient both in case of database and excel in order to send them mail separately in one go @AdinugrahaTawaqal

Comment: You are already looping through all of the recipients when you do `Msg.To.Add(row["address"].ToString());`. You just need to refactor the code to also update the html and send the email

Comment: how can i do that? @Scrobi

Answer (score 1):

Use
`Msg.Bcc.Add(sample@sample.com);` 
instead of
`Msg.To.Add(sample@sample.com);`

[See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bcc?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void SendEMail(string to, string subject, string body)
{
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 587);

    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

    smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("my@com.pl", "12345!");

    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("\"" + Info.SiteName + "\" <" + Info.EMail + ">", "recipient1@gmail.com");

    mailMessage.Bcc.Add("recipient2@gmail.com");
    mailMessage.Bcc.Add("recipient3@gmail.com");
    mailMessage.Bcc.Add("recipient4@gmail.com");
    mailMessage.Bcc.Add("recipient5@gmail.com");
    mailMessage.Bcc.Add("recipient6@gmail.com");

    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

    mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;

    mailMessage.Body = body;
    mailMessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    mailMessage.Subject = subject;
    mailMessage.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think me writing the code for you will help you learn. Also the issue you are having does not seem to be with the programming language but the the logical steps that the program needs to take to achieve its goal.

Before you start writing code you may be better off writing down the these steps.

You will also be better off breaking this task down into small chunks of code.

From what I can tell from your code a User fills in their details on a form in order to send an email to a list of Recipients.

I have broken the steps down into different methods, I hope this helps. Fill in each method with what it it needs to do and no more. Make sure each step works before moving onto to the next one. I think you have most of the code to do this it just needs restructuring.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string user = GetUserDetails();
    List<string> recipients = GetAllRecipient();
    string html = GetHtmlTemplate();
    foreach (var recipient in recipients)
    {
        html = html.Replace("<<SOME TAG>>", recipient);
        SendEmail(recipient, html);
    }
}

public string GetUserDetails()
{
    return txtUsername.Text;
}

public List<string> GetAllRecipient()
{
    //TODO: Get all your recipient from database or excel
    //e,g, 
    return new List<string>() {"someemail@address.com", "anotheremail@address.com"};
}

public void SendEmail(string recipient, string html)
{
    //TODO: Send the email
}
```

The steps that I can identify are:
User - clicks Button

- Step 1: Get users details
- Step 2: Get all recipients
- Step 3: Get Html template
- Step 4: For each recipient => Update html template with
  unique link and send email.

Comment: i want to know two things- 1. Can't i loop through the recipients so that the email would be sent to them separately? 2. Is it possible to do so in one button click event or not? @Scrobi                                                                                                                                    Forget about the html part. The main issue is i am not able to send the mail separately using for loop as above. I don't want the bcc option

Comment: i have done everything and still mail is delivered to all at once. Pls check my for loop for each row. i guess something is wrong there

Comment: for (int a = 0; a < dt.Rows.Count; a++)
                    {
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        Msg.To.Add(row["address"].ToString());

                 
                        SendHTMLMail(); }}

Comment: the second loop is calling  SendHTMLMail() function for all rows altogether

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the context of this code now, can you update the code in the question please.

Comment: Ok it looks like the `GetAllRecipient` and `SendHTMLMail` are both still doing too much and depending on the radio button selected there is different behaviour. Which radio button selection are you currently testing with and we can sort that one first.

Comment: radiobutton 1 is for database i am checking it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178664/discussion-between-scrobi-and-manu-sharma).